# Multiplying numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy

I have written a function to multiply two numpy arrays.

```
def ra(self):
    """Multiply Rotation with initial Values"""
    rva = self.r_array() * self.va_array()
    rva = np.sum(rva, axis=1)  # Sum rows of Matrix
    rva = np.array([[rva[0]],  # Transpose Matrix
                    [rva[1]],
                    [rva[2]]])
```

where:

- r_array has 3 rows and 3 columns
- va_array has 3 rows and 1 column

I feel like this should be able to be written in one line. However, `self.r_array() * self.va_array()` always returns a 3 x 3 array.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21563036 Use `r_array.dot(va_array)`  or `@` operator.

Comment: @Peilonrayz - Thank you for the welcome. My code did work as intended, hence why I posted it here and not at in Stack Overflow. I generated a workaround that produced the correct answer but was not elegant. The problem was that I did not know how to do this in one line. This was correctly answered below, however.

Comment: So it does, my apologies.

Comment: Questions like this are common on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `*` operator does element-wise multiplication. So you need to use .dot() function to get the desired result.

Example :

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]])

b =  np.array([[1]
    ,[2],
    [3]])
print(a * b)
print(a.dot(b))
```

output :

```py
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [21 24 27]]
[[14]
 [32]
 [50]]
```

Observe that when I have used `*` operator, every column in a is multiplied with b element-wise

Comment: @sai-sreenivas - Thank you for the answer. That worked to get it down to one line. It was working as intended before (unlike was suggesting and thus I dispute that it was off-topic) but this has made it significantly more elegant.

Comment: Why does this output different numbers to the OPs? OPs outputs 6, 30, 72 where yours outputs 14, 32, 50.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
 np.sum(r_array*va_array, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

To match `r_array@va_array`, use `va_array.T` in the 1liner.